# How to ensure a string is a valid filename/path?

Tags: c++, error-handling, filesystems, filenames

What is the most appropriate way of ensuring that a string (user input) is a valid text file path? And also the extension part should be either **.txt** or empty.

I have considered two approaches:

```
const std::string_view filename {"setup"};

// Check if the filename is valid
std::error_code ec;
if (!std::filesystem::path(filename).has_filename() || !std::filesystem::exists(filename, ec) ||
    std::filesystem::path(filename).extension() != "" && std::filesystem::path(filename).extension() != ".txt")
{
    return false;
}
```

or:

```
const std::string_view filename {"setup"};

// Check if the filename is valid
if (std::filesystem::path(filename).extension() != "" && std::filesystem::path(filename).extension() != ".txt")
{
    return false;
}
std::istream ifs { filename };
if (!ifs.is_open()) // or if (!ifs) or if (ifs.fail())
{
    return false;
}
```

I have to mention that `exists()` is not what I want though since I would rather directly open the file for a read operation using an `ifstream` (instead of checking for its existence first).

There is also a function named [`is_regular_file()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file) which I guess I need to add to the above checks.

Is the second approach sufficient for handling any potential errors (e.g. invalid characters used in the user input, wrong extension, file not opening, wrong [file type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_type), etc)?

Comment: You can never know that for a fact. You can *try* to check things, but you can never know for sure. You just have to deal with that..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oh OK. I guess I'm trying to check stuff as best as I can programmatically. However, I still need suggestions (if there are any).

Comment: Open/Create the file, if this is successful then the path is valid.  Also if there was a _"valid path name test"_, then you have a race condition as the path may no longer be valid when you come to use it.  So you may as well just use the path and handle the errors.

Comment: I dont understand whats wrong with the second approach. Or rather, only the second half of the second approach.  If you try to open the file via `std::istream ifs { filename };` then you do cover all potential errors, because either it succeeds or not.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the path is not structurally/syntactically valid?`path`'s constructor will throw an exception if that is the case.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai How should I check then? `is_open()` covers it all? Or do I need to check `.fail()` as well?

Comment: afaik at that point `is_open` being false is all that can go wrong, but not sure. See example here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail. Note also the table at the bottom, looks complicated, but thats mainly due to `eof` which you can only hit after attempting to read from the stream

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I guess you're right. Failure to open the file sets the failbit. They all do the same thing as `is_open()`.

Comment: Be aware of [TOC/TOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) issues that can occur.

Comment: @JesperJuhl True. But I think a call to `is_open()` that returns `true` should be sufficient. I'll keep the file open as long as the read operation finishes.

Comment: @digito_evo "No". A successful call to `is_open` only means something the instant it it is called. 1 nanosecond later it can be invalid.

Comment: @JesperJuhl How? Like the file being deleted while being open?

Comment: @digito_evo Yeah, like the file being deleted or written to or being extended or just simply being read. Or for that matter; someone unplugging the drive holding the file. You can't assume atomic operations on files.

Comment: @JesperJuhl [`is_open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/is_open) checks whether last call to `open()` was successful and there was no `close()` in between. That cannot change. What could change is the ability to read/write that file (though I think on Linux once you open a file handle, it will work until you close it even if the file was removed in the meantime?)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sure. I know the usual Linux file semantics. But what if someone unplugs the drive ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::fstream::is_open` will still report `true` at the very least :)

Comment: Indeed, a file resource can become unavailable for various reasons. Network shares are a more obvious example of that. Standard practice is to not assume that you'll be able to read from the file just because you opened it. If it's important to you, then you must handle any errors that occur during reading as well. It's not sufficient to assume that successful opening of the file is the end of your problems.

Comment: @paddy Right. Especially with network file systems.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There are almost no syntactic rules for pathnames on Linux. I'm not sure about Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file might exist, but you cannot tell (programmatically or not) because you (or the executable) simply lack the appropriate permissions.

[std::filesystem::exists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) is your best option for checking existence. As for checking the extension, [std::filesystem::path::extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/extension) is a good place to start.

> I would rather directly open the file for a read operation using an `ifstream` (instead of checking for its existence first).

You can sure try. Just make sure the stream is valid before you try reading anything from it. Your sample of `!ifs` is my personal preference; the stream has an implicit boolean conversion which returns `false` if it's invalid.

One note: you should avoid repeatedly calling `std::filesystem::path(filename)`. This constructs a new `path` instance each time. Construct one, and then interrogate it as necessary.